# Meteor uses API – pickadate.js but I am not able to get unix timestamp working for that

Tags: javascript, unix, meteor, pickadate

According to api http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/ . I am using following code to get unix timestamp given the date.

First I set:

```
$('.startDate').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    });
```

then I tried:

```
console.log($('.startDate').get('picker'))
console.log($('.endDate').get('select','pick'))
```

But, its not printing anything for both of these statement. I am expecting answer in this format

> 1476772363 that is 1476772363 seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC) for selected date

. however for

```
console.log($('.endDate').val())
```

it prints

> 20 October, 2016

Answer (score 0):

$('.startDate').get('select') should return the date.

Add a format pattern if needed.

$('.startDate').get('select', 'yyyy/mm/dd')

This way you can create a moment with the output for better manipulation.

Hope it helps,
Yann

Comment: nope i am looking for unix time equivalent of this date

Comment: $('.startDate').get('select').obj should return the js Date object

Comment: and the Date object will be in milliseconds, so divide by 1000

Comment: whats .obj there is no such property